# How could i confige postfix as an SMTP server that i can log into?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, smtp, postfix-mta

I have a laravel app that needs to connect to an external SMTP server and log in to send a email. How could i configure my local postfix to be said server and have the app log into it? I already have postfix completely set up with proper dns and domain names (MX, etc) and it works flawlessly for sending emails through the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Laravel to use your local SMTP server.

You can try that in your .env configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```